# Distribution of conditional independence

Tags: probability, distributions, independence, conditional

I have random variables W,A,Z,U and know that the following conditional independence holds: $W \perp (A,Z)|U$. Is it correct to then state that $W|ZA\sim W|U$?

My reasoning is the following but am unsure if it holds:

$p(w|az)=\int_U p(w,u|az) du=\int_U p(w|azu)p(u|az)du=\int_U p(w|u)p(u|az)du=p(w|u)\int_U p(u|za)du = p(w|u)$

In such case would it follow that $E[W|ZA]=E[W|U]$ and thus $E[W]=E_U[E[W|U]]= E_U[E[W|ZA]]$?